# OnGestureListener onDown method never gets called

Tags: android, gesture

My `onScroll` and  are`onTouchEvent` getting called, but not the `onDown` method. In fact, when I log the `distaceX` in `onDown` I get several of them logged out, and the first is always relative to the spot where I ended the last scroll.

```
 @Override 
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){ 
   this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);

  return super.onTouchEvent(me); 
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
       Log.d("---onDown---",".");
   return false;

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
   float distanceY) {
  Log.d("---onScroll---", "" + distanceX);
  return false;
 }
```

Any ideas why `onDown` would not be called?

EDIT:

I changed my `onTouchEvent` to the following block, and only the ACTION_MOVE gets logged.

```
 float gestureDistance = 0;
 @Override 
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){ 
     switch (me.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:               
            Log.d("actionDown", "gestureDistance:" + gestureDistance);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("actionUp", "gestureDistance:" + gestureDistance);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d("actionMove", "gestureDistance:" + gestureDistance);
            break;
        default:
            Log.d("action default", "default");
            break;
    }
```

EDIT:
I think the problem is that my view is a WebView.  Can I keep the webview from stealing my events?

Comment: Just tried to test the same code. I get onDown events successfully . What device do you use?

Comment: try `return true;` instead. See if that works.

Comment: I've tried `return true;`.  Same results and the Log never happens.

Comment: I'm using a Droid2 with 2.2 installed.

Comment: Do I need to do something special in my onCreate or manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to my `onCreate` fixed the problem.

```
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {        

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:               
            //Do something on action down.
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //Do something on action up.
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //Do something when moving.
            break;
    }   

    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Only the ACTION_MOVE gets called.  I've edited my question with more info.

Comment: well then I don't know what's wrong then. Are you using a physical device or are you testing on the emulator?